# Crystal Reports error on web server but not localhost

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, runtime-error

I'm trying to rewrite a desktop app to a web app. When I run it through Visual Studio on localhost, it works. But when I publish it to the server and run it there, it throws this exception when trying to use Crystal Reports:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ReportSourceClass' to interface type 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ISCRReportSource'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{31E7715A-8AD0-4D1C-958E-C1BE0A6F2D0C}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50177685) and tried adding the `<dependentAssembly>`s, but no change. I tried removing the manually-added GAC references and replacing them with NuGet. Deleting bin+obj. Rebuilding. Nothing does anything.

What's going on here?

Comment: @Austin Copy the entire folder? Like, the solution folder with the '.vs' and '.sln' and the '.csproj's and everything? I've never tried running that on a server before, but I guess I'll try?... Yeah that didn't work. Just gives "Server Error in '/MyApp' Application.".

Comment: @Austin I just figured out that part - It wasn't publishing that file because it was in the Core project, and apparently you can only include additional files to publish if they're in the project you're publishing. So it's publishing with the .rpt now. Still throwing the InvalidCastException, sadly.