# Unable to cast COM object of type (No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)))

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, crystal-reports

**Unable to cast COM object of type 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ReportSourceClass' to interface type 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ISCRReportSource'.**
[image]

In my local machine everything work properly.When i published it it the error in the crystal report i try to solve all type of token problem but after solving token problem its show this type of problem .But i don't get any type of solution this type of problem.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: I would also suggest Googling for `reportsourceclass to interface type ISCRReportSource` and reading some of the 188 results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows form application error with crystal report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46556393/windows-form-application-error-with-crystal-report)

Comment: This solution not solve my problem.

Comment: I solved my problem. if any one need any help contact with me.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem.

1. At first you check your report Folder and all reports goes to the server.
   if don't go to the server please set report **Build Action** as **Content**
2. Then Check you you reference and dll. And set
   all **Crystal Decisions**  reference **Copy Local** **True** like as[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X58IB.png)
3. Then check you Computer **Crystal Reports Service Pack** if you install Service Pack 22  then in your virtual pc must be install **RUNTIME Service Pack 22**
   I hope if every thing is ok then it work properly.